# How to set splitter exactly to half window width in p4merge?

Tags: p4merge

I'm wondering if there is a way to set the splitter in p4merge window exactly to 50% screen width. For instance in **Total Commander** you can right click on splitter and choose from list but there is nothing like that in p4merge.

[image: p4merge splitter]

Answer (score 1):

I used [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals to track where p4merge writes settings.
Appears that settings file resides here

> %USERPROFILE%\.p4merge\ApplicationSettings.xml

and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--perforce-xml-version=1.0-->
<PropertyList varName="ApplicationSettings" IsManaged="TRUE">
 <String varName="CharSet">utf8-bom</String>
 <PropertyList varName="Connection" IsManaged="TRUE">
  <String varName="ApplicationLanguage">en</String>
 </PropertyList>
 <String varName="DiffOption">dl</String>
 <ByteArray varName="DiffSplitter">AAAA/wAAAAAAAAACAAAA8wAAAUMBAAAAMgEAAAAB</ByteArray>
 <Font varName="Font">
  <family>Courier</family>
  <pointSize>10</pointSize>
  <weight>Normal</weight>
  <italic>false</italic>
 </Font>
 <!--i cut it here for concise-->
</PropertyList>
```

My guess was:

```
<ByteArray varName="DiffSplitter">AAAA/wAAAAAAAAACAAAA8wAAAUMBAAAAMgEAAAAB</ByteArray>
```

is a place where p4merge stores the splitter position.

I didn't feel like decrypting the value so i just deleted the whole tag and splitter moved to exactly 50% width of window.